# Angular Datatables select row programmatically

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-datatables

I have Angular 8 app with Angular Datatables plugin.

And I want to select row programmatically based on `id` param from url `http://localhost:5000/users;id=1`.

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
    this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
});
```

Also I use server side processing as in official [example](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way)

How can I do that?

Comment: The paramMap will help you to _parse_ the URL, this should work with this URL : `http://localhost:5000/users?id=1`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to get the param Id from the URL, then to filter the datatable 
You need to do something like this :

- Inside your Template add a `datatable` reference to trigger after with the `ViewChild`

  ```
   <table datatable #datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
  ```
- Inside the component

  ```
  @ViewChild('datatable') dt: DataTable;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.selectedId = params.get("id")

      console.log(id);
    })

  datatableFilter(){
    this.persons = this.persons.filter( rec -> { rec.id === this.id  return rec} );
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

[As DataTable docs says:](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().select())

> row().select() - Select a single row.

An example of selection of the first row:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

table.row(':eq(0)', { page: 'current' }).select();
```

So you need to figure out the number of row by `id` and use the above code. Your code should like this:

```
let selectedRow = this.persons.findIndex(f => f.id ==  this.selectedId);
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();     
table.row(`:eq(${selectedRow} )`, { page: 'current' }).select();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with the following way:

```
<table [dtOptions]="dtOptions" datatable>
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngIf="users.length != 0">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of users" [class.table-success]="item.id == selectedId">
        ...
```